# Using weak property not like a protocol

Tags: objective-c, properties

As you know, when we apply a protocol which must declare a delegate.

```
@property (weak) id<NameOfProtocol> delegate;
```

But, Xcode shows the fault message when I declare like this (not use protocol)

```
@property (weak) id<NameOfObject> pointer;
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: put the code of your header file up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you go

```
@property (weak) id<NameOfProtocol> delegate;
```

you are saying i want a variable that points some type that conforms to NameOfProtocol. you need it to be a `id` type because you dont actually know what the variables type is going to be (and you dont care so long as it implements the methods from NameOfProtocol)

while

```
@property (weak) id<NameOfObject> pointer;
```

doesnt make sense because you are saying i want a variable, but i dont know the type therefore i need `id` but it conforms to NameOfObject... which is contradictory since you have the type

therefore you should have just a normal weak variable in this case

```
@property (weak) NameOfObject *pointer;
```

Comment: Thank for your explain :). I understood

Comment: no problem, should mark it as the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

`@property (weak) id<NameOfProtocol> delegate;`

means the variable can be any type if it conforms to NameOfProtocol

`@property (weak) id<NameOfObject> pointer;`

means the variable can be any type but it type must be NameOfObject

so it have no sense;

instead of

`@property (weak) NameOfObject *pointer;`